# Grouping with list - in df.groupby seems not working

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use a list to group the rows as one of the ways of grouping in pandas.

## The objective:

I want to group **N number of rows** from the data frame - so I took the approach in which groupby takes list as an input and groups rows in that order. Before going through the problem, let me show you the code that I am using to group rows.

```py
import math

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 5)))

# Number or rows in group
n_elems = 20

# Total rows in the dataset
n_rows = df.shape[0]

# Groups to be created (Taking ceil to deal with even / odd number of rows)
n_groups = math.ceil(n_rows / n_elems)

groups = []
for idx in range(n_groups):
    grp = [idx] * n_elems
    groups.extend(grp)
    
# Making the same length - as groupby requires
groups = groups[:n_rows]

# Using list ↓ to group by
df.groupby(groups).agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

## The problem:

Now, in this case - the algorithm works fine when I take number of rows per groups from 1 to 19.
Making 100 groups if n_rows is 1, 50 groups if n_rows is 2, 20 groups if n_rows is 5 and likewise till 19.

But the problem appears from number 20. I don't know why 20, it could be other number based on the other length of rows, but here giving n_rows as 20, it should return 5 groups involving 20 rows in each. But it returns weird looking dataframe with 100 rows but 0 columns!

---

I tried to look up but didn't find anything useful. Any help would make my understanding of groupby better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output of this is a lot. What are you trying to do with this code. Can you demonstrate the behaviour you want on a scale smaller than 100 rows?

Comment: I have 10 rows, I want to group by rows - not by categories as usual - as we do. So I want to make groups of 2 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 2 rows making total 5 groups out of 10 rows. Okay, now from those I can do whatever like mean, median, sum and other stuff, But the thing is about combining rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating groups by floor dividing the `index` instead:

```
n_elems = 2
new_df = df.groupby(df.index // n_elems).agg(['mean', 'sum'])
```

```
      0          1          2     
   mean  sum  mean  sum  mean  sum
0  57.5  115  75.5  151  34.5   69
1  71.0  142  17.0   34  53.0  106
2  21.0   42  48.5   97  78.5  157
```

---

Sample DF Used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (6, 3)))
```

`df`:

```
    0   1   2
0  99  78  61
1  16  73   8
2  62  27  30
3  80   7  76
4  15  53  80
5  27  44  77
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! But I am wondering why? Like if I convert my list into the Index by pd.Index then it works. Would you please guide me on what makes the difference between providing a list and the index to the group?

Comment: So you _can_ do this also with  `df.groupby(pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])).agg(['mean', 'sum'])`  or `df.groupby(np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])).agg(['mean', 'sum'])` but it needs to be something that can `align` a dataframe. Check out under `by` in the docs [DataFrame groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)